# Using GPS's data with robot_pose_ekf in Gazebo simulation

Tags: gazebo, navigation, gazebo-simulator, gps-common, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I am now doing simulation of robot with a GPS sensor attached. The sensor plugin I used is the GPS plugin provided by the Hector team. The way I make use of the GPS data is as followed: I use the utm_odometry node to first convert the GPS's fix data into odom message, then I will input the odom message into the  robot_pose_ekf as the “vo” inputs.

However, I run into a problem with the robot_pose_ekf node. For robot_pose_ekf, it cannot process message with zero diagonal covariance matrix.

This is my GPS sensor's fix output,

```
header: 
  seq: 41
  stamp: 
  secs: 10
  nsecs: 500000000
frame_id: base_footprint
 status: 
 status: 0
 service: 1
latitude: 49.8999981297
longitude: 8.90000579613
altitude: -0.0689502682112
position_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
position_covariance_type: 0
```

This is the utm_odometry node's output,

```
header: 
 seq: 307
 stamp: 
 secs: 77
 nsecs: 0
frame_id: base_footprint
child_frame_id: ''
pose: 
pose: 
position: 
  x: 492817.988235
  y: 5527516.10598
  z: -0.385949522131
orientation: 
  x: 1.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
  w: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 99999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
99999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 99999.0]
twist: 
 twist: 
 linear: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Both the simulated GPS's fix and odom output from utm_odometry node have diagonal zeros in their covariance matrix. I wonder if this is considered normal? If so, does that means that the outputs from simulated GPS sensors cannot be input into utm_odometry -->robot_pose_ekf?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50448/using-gps%27s-data-with-robot_pose_ekf-in-gazebo-simulation/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2012-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may be a limitation of the utm_odometry node.  Looking at the hector_gazebo plugin, the covariance matrix is zeroed, but there is another element in the NavSatFix message called position_covariance_type that is set to  sensor_msgs::NavSatFix::COVARIANCE_TYPE_UNKNOWN by the hector GPS plugin.  There appears to be a discussion of this field [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10310/calculate-navsatfix-covariance/).

Looking at the source code of utm_odometry node appears to ignore this field and just examines the covariance matrix.  The code can be found around [line 54](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/gps_common/html/utm__odometry__node_8cpp_source.html).

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-12-14**:
I see. Thanks. I think i will find another way to make use of the GPS data then.